# submit button on html to output result on same page

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, webforms

Although this seems like something very basic, but no matter what I tried I couldn't get my head around it. Basically I want a html form where a user types in their ID number in an input text box and when they hit the submit button it displays their email address which is their company ID number @ company.com, such as below

```
<form action=""> ID Number: <input
type="text" name="idnumber" /><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Whats my
email address" /> </form> <p>Your
email address is
'idnumber'@email.com</p>
```

Can this even be done using html or would I need to use  Javascript or PHP for it?

Thanks

Comment: HTML 5 might be able to do this, but otherwise you will need Javascript or PHP for it...

Comment: can you help me to do it with javascript or PHP then please? will the results be outputed in the same page? Thanks

Comment: You'll need to set the `method` attribute of your `form` tag: `<form action="#" method="post">` (or `method="get"`).

Comment: @BloodPhilia The HTML in HTML5 can't do this, and that is good, as it is definitely a *behaviour*.

Comment: @alex HTML5 can store local data (client-side) and then use/display that data, so it should be possible. Also check [this](http://www.webreference.com/authoring/languages/html/HTML5-Client-Side/)

Comment: @BloodPhilia But you need to use JavaScript to write it, yeah?

Comment: @alex Technically, yes... But it's still an HTML5 feature... ;)

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript

#### HTML

```
ID Number: <input
type="text" name="idnumber" id="idnumber" /><br/>
<p>Your
email address is
<span id="emailid"></span>@email.com</p>
```

#### JavaScript

```
var input = document.getElementById('idnumber'),
    placeholder = document.getElementById('emailid');

input.onkeyup = function() {
   placeholder.innerHTML = input.value
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/ECCDG/).

Be sure to attach to `window.onload` or a DOM ready event.

This version will update on key up - if you want to use the button, reference the button and use the event `onclick`.

---

### PHP

#### HTML/PHP

```
<form action="?" method="get"> ID Number: <input
type="text" name="idnumber" /><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Whats my
email address" /> </form> <p>Your
email address is
<?php echo isset($_GET['idnumber']) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['idnumber']) : ''; ?>@email.com</p>
```

You could use POST here as well, but GET will be clearer as a beginner (and refreshing won't invoke the browser's *Submit form again* dialogue).

If using POST, you should really follow [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) (that Wikipedia URL is *terrible*). Except in this case you need a value to persist, which you could use cookie, session or GET param, easier just to use GET from the get go :)

Comment: I used the HTML/PHP Method, but its not quite working right though, its live on http://pixeldots.co.uk/

Comment: @amateur You have a few problems there, namely the PHP is being taking literally - are you adding this to a CMS? It needs to be ran as PHP, so you can't just have it saved as text and then render it as text. Also, I updated the code, so you should use that. If you can't get around the CMS limitation, use the JavaScript version.

Comment: Thanks for that, Yes I am using a CMS, WordPress, with the javascript can I just embed it into the html page or does it need to be stored externally?

Comment: @amateur You can embed it, but you may need to use *code* view. It is best practice however to keep JavaScript in external files.

Answer (score 0):

php or javascript will help you.

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<div>
Welcome <?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_GET["email"]; ?>
</div>
<p id="output"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

**Using JavaScript**  adding this code inside of your html/php script

```
<script>
function getIndex() {
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML =
document.getElementById("email").selectedIndex;
}
</script>
```